# Reuse test_func for UserPassesTestMixin in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Suppose I have 2 view classes

```
class View1(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Do something and render a page

    def test_func(self):
        #Validation logic

class View2(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Do something and response with JsonResponse

    def test_func(self):
        #The exact same validation logics as the test_func for View1
```

How can I in my Django code don't repeat the same test_func twice?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
class MyPermissionRules(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        #my rules here

class View1(MyPermissionRules, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Do something and render a page

class View2(MyPermissionRules, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Do something and response with JsonResponse
```

In this way the same rule can be reused